# Given a subspace $W$ of $V$ and a linearly independent set $A \subseteq W$, is $A$ linearly independent in $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can you please show that, if a set $A$ is linearly independent in $W$, a subspace of $V$, then it is linearly independent in $V$? Thank you.

Here is my attempt.

Let $A = \{ a_1, a_2, \cdots , a_n \}$ linearly independent in $W$. By L.I. in $W$, I am considering it L.I. over $F$ and a subset of $W$. (I am not sure about that.) Now, to show it is L.I. in $V$, I know, it is a subset of $V$. I am stuck for the other part. If it is L.I. over $F$, it should be trivially true for all subspaces containing $A$. But how? I know any subspace containing $A$, contains $Span(A)$. Now, if $x_1 a_1+ x_2 a_2 + \cdots + x_n a_n = 0_V$ in $V$ ($0_V$ is additive identity in $V$ and $\forall i \ x_i \in F$). Then, this particular combination belongs to W too. And as $0_V=0_W$ (additive identity of $W$) So, should I write $x_1 a_1+ x_2 a_2 + \cdots + x_n a_n = 0_W$ in $W$? If so, how? I know if this is the case, then we have $\forall i \  x_i = 0$, and thus the result follows.

Edit:
I am trying to prove this, in layman's terms.

Suppose, b1. w1 + b2. w2 .... bn. wn = 0v in V.
Now,  (b1. w1 + b2. w2 .... + bn. wn) belongs to W, as Span(A) is a subset of W.

Let, (b1. w1 + b2. w2 .... bn. wn)= l, l belongs to W.

so, l= (b1. w1 + b2. w2 .... bn. wn)= 0v in V. as l belongs to V too.

now, for any w of W, w+l = w+0v = w (as w belongs to V, as W is a subset of V)
Here, w+l = w is an equation in W. adding both side by (-w), an element of W, we get,
(-w) + w + l = (-w)+w ;
=> 0w+l=0w ;
=> l =0w.

So, (b1. w1 + b2. w2 .... bn. wn)= 0w in W.
So, we have bi= 0 for all i.
So, A is Linealy independent in V.

Comment: Is your question supposed to be: “If a set $A$ is linearly independent in a subspace W of V, then is it linearly independent in $V$?"

Comment: Yeah. Definitely

Comment: Could you please make it clear what exactly do you mean by "linearly independent in a subspace"? And how it is different from being linearly independent in the whole set? Also, please clarify if $0_V$ and $0_W$ are different objects, and if not, why would you use two different symbols? If you are not sure how to formalise your thoughts, consider using the concepts of _direct sum_ and _projection_ (not orthogonal, but the general one), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace#Sum) is a suggested starting point.

Comment: LI in a subspace means I guess, LI over F and a subset of W. And 0v=0w. And what would be it's complement subspace?

Comment: Can anyone please give me concrete proof just using the basics?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Yes.

Let $\{ v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n \}$ be a basis of $V$, and $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_m\}$ for $m \le n$ be a basis of $W$. We can always choose such a basis for a subspace $W$. We are given some linearly independent set $A \subseteq W$. Each $a \in A$ can be written as a linear combination as elements of $w$: $a = \sum_{i=1}^m c_i v_i$, with the condition that $\sum_{i=1}^m c_{i}v_i = 0 \iff$ $c_i = 0$ for $i = 1,2,\dots,m$. However, notice that $$a = \sum_{i=1}^m c_{i}v_i = \sum_{i=1}^m c_iv_i + \sum_{m+1}^n 0v_i,$$ therefore $a \in V$ and not all of the $c_i$ are zero.

Comment: How can i be sure that, Vi, i<=m are elements of W?

Comment: @AnubhabPahari $W$ is a subspace of $V$, so we can always choose a basis for $W$ such that it is like the basis of $V$ except it just lacks a few elements (if $V$ is not the same space as $W$).

Comment: Can we prove it? I mean not using the property of my question? Because if we prove it, i think it answers my question.

Comment: And I appreciate your effort.

Comment: Prove which part, exactly? That if we pick $m$ out of the $n$ vectors that form a basis of $V$, we will get a new subspace $W$?

Comment: No. You are telling random subspace, I am telling particular.

Comment: There is the [change of basis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis) which allows us to transform any basis of $W$ into the form that I mentioned. Also, it is **a** basis, not “the” basis, therefore we can construct $W$ in a matter which suits our proof best.

Comment: So because we can have more than one basis, I just picked the most convenient basis for our proof. If, say, $V$ had basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ and $W$ had basis $\{2,2x,2x^2\}$, then we could scale each element of $W$ by $\frac{1}{2}$ in our proof, but there is no reason to do this since we may construct $W$ in a manner that makes our proof the cleanest instead of changing the existing basis.

Comment: Just to reassure you, we aren't doing anything "fishy" with our construction. We do not place limits on how $W$ is, how many elements the basis has (it could even be equal to $V$). There are no restrictions placed on $W$, all we know that it is a subspace of $V$, which is what we need. Any subspace of $W$ will use a basis of $V$ somehow, it is up to us to choose how to use it. If we were given a basis before hand, then yes we would need to transform it first but after that the proof would still be the same.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. I have done a proof. can you please review it. Just another approach.